# Check a property of all items in a list is equal

Tags: list, arraylist, groovy

```
List1[[name:'mohit',roll:'1305'],[name:'mohit',roll:'2414']]
```

How to compare whether the 2 names are equal or not??

What i mean is `list1.get(name)==???`

Comment: What is List1 thing there?  is this a list of two maps?  It looks like it should be `list1[0].name==list1[1].name` -- or if you have any number of maps in that list, you might be better off with the `.every` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a few ways to check if `name` keys hold the same value for both (or all) maps inside the list.

Assuming:

```
def list = [[name:'mohit',roll:'1305'],[name:'mohit',roll:'2414']]
```

If you have only two (or at most two) maps inside the list, you can compare directly values for `name` key, e.g.

```
assert list.getAt(0)?.name == list.getAt(1)?.name
```

Above construction is alternative for `list[0]?.name == list[1]?.name`. The main difference is that `.getAt(index)` wont throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if your list does not contain two elements.

In case of checking if all elements inside the list hold the same value for `name` key you can transform the list to hold unique list of names and check if its size is equal to 1:

```
assert list.collect { it.name }.unique().size() == 1
```

Instead of using `.unique()` which creates a list you can use more traditional way and call `.toSet()` method which will create a `Set` instead of a list (`Set` contains only unique values):

```
assert list.collect { it.name }.toSet().size() == 1
```

Finally, instead of collect you can use Groovy's spread operator:

```
assert list*.name.toSet().size() == 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment but not able to retrieve the name from the list..But i did like the set approach..Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MohitBaid What do you mean you are not able to retrieve the name from the list? Do you get any specific error?

Comment: Stepnaik What's happening is from the console I am not being able to fetch the elements of the list..List.get(0).name.. this name i am not being able to fetch..So thinking for a different approach